# Wget does -m need to be used with -r --no-parent argument

Tags: wget

Title pretty much says it all. If i want to mirror a website directories and sub directories. should i use `wget -m -r --no-parent bla.com` or should i use `wget -r --no-parent bla.com`. Is -m needed?

Answer (score 1):

The `-m` option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. It is currently equivalent to `‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’`. Source http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Answer (score 0):

By default the `-r` option goes down 5 levels which might be enough in your case but, if you need more levels, use the `-l` option followed by a number (of levels) or just use `-l inf` for infinite depth.
As others have answered, the option `-m` does the latter and also enables timestamp checks and listing of FTP directories.
In the example that you provided, the option `--no-parent` will prevent retrieving pages or resources from above the level of the target URL, although in your case it looks like a root URL (but it could be any level below).
Finally keep in mind that by default `wget` doesn't retrieve resources outside the domain of the target URL so you might miss CSS and JavaScript files that were placed above the target URL or in other domains.